# Conditionally add row in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got a simple repeating table-row in AngularJS

```html
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>{{ item.prop1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.prop2 }}</td>
</tr>
```

My `item` object has a `comment` property on it, and if that comment contains a value, I want to display that in a row all by itself on the line right after the rest of the elements and have it span the entire row.  Is that type of thing possible?  I looked at ng-repeat-end but that doesn't seem to be what I want, and I can't just add and extra <tr> element inside the ng-repeat as that'd be invalid HTML.

Comment: this is harder than it looks!

Comment: Who is putting downvote . leave the comment what is wrong in answer

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want `ng-repeat-end`, as what I've read in your entire post, it would be the most probable solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[ng-repeat's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)** special repeat start and end points via `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/HCeBUbjN8Ahv20n8A6tx?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<table ng-controller="PostController">
  <tr ng-repeat-start="post in posts">
    <td>{{post.content}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
    <td>{{comment.content}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE: If the comment is a string, then simply remove the `ng-repeat` at the `ng-repeat-end` end point and add an `ng-if` expression that validates the existence of `post.comment`.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/4SA53TfTrMYsUCI6HXL5?p=preview)**

**HTML**

```
<table ng-controller="PostController">
  <tr ng-repeat-start="post in posts">
    <td>{{post.content}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="post.comment">
    <td>{{post.comment}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The comment isn't an array, it's just a single string property.

Comment: if it is then, simply remove the ng-repeat and add `post.comment` at the `ng-repeat-end` end point?

Comment: add an `ng-if="post.comment"` to verify its existince.